# Installing Ubuntu Desktop on Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, software-installation, windows-7, desktop-environments

I can't seem to install Ubuntu Desktop on my Windows 7 PC.  Once it was done
downloading Cyberlink Power2Go opened up and told me that "No burner is
currently available or you don't have rights to access the burner"
Not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.  Any advice?

Also, I have been told that I need a disk burner to make this work, but I do not currently have one, and I'd rather not buy one to make it work.

Comment: This is a Windows error and hence is off-topic here..

Comment: it could also be seen as another reason Ubuntu is terrible.  as it is, the list is pretty long already

Comment: If you think Ubuntu is terrible, why would you want to install it in the first place?

Comment: need it for class

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to download the ISO image file, and save that file to your computer.  Probably "right-clicking" the download link and select "save link as..." is the best option for you.

If you do not have a CD (or DVD) burner, then you can use a USB flash drive that is large enough to hold the contents of the ISO.  (If you have one large enough, You could probably use a SD Card as well, but I have never done it with an SD card).

1. Download the ISO image

   - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors
2. Load it on a USB drive:

   - Yumi - http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/
   - Unetbootin - https://unetbootin.github.io/
   - Pen Drive Linux - http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
   - UUI = http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/