# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 from a Flash Drive Issues

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a freshly formatted flash drive that I am attempting to install Ubuntu onto my laptop with, however I get an error saying

```
[ 0.046575] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected 1)
```

A nice fellow whom I can no longer get a hold of had informed me to replace a bit of code with nomodeset, however all this does is run a small amount of script which ends with it saying mapper loaded and nothing happening, not even able to type commands. Please help, this is my first time attempting to use any linux distro!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, I don't have enough points to use comments.

Which tool did you use to make your bootable USB?

There are some options this answer:
[Installing Ubuntu Desktop on Windows 7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671778/installing-ubuntu-desktop-on-windows-7/671794#671794)

Comment: I used UUI, the one on pendrivelinux (the website not the tool)

Comment: Okay, I haven't used that one before, I've use lili, yumi and unetbootin.  Perhaps try a newer version of Ubuntu, 15.04.  That seems to a problem with the boot splash screens.   I would say that your problem is actually something else.